# asterisk MeetMe no video?

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, conference

I am working on asterisk 1.8 Ubuntu 9.10. I am testing a video conference, but no video, just audio. Why? I am working with MeetMe method

In extensions.conf I've written exten => 1234,MeetMe(1234) where 1234 is a conf room from Meetme.conf. Where do I set what codec should be send for video? And how can I set a timing for the conference call? Not earlier with more than 10 minutes?

How to create dynamic conference rooms? What is a dynamic conference room? Thx. Appreciate
Can someone please post some configuration lines?

I am new to this stuff. Appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic conference room is room that was NOT defined in config.
You can create on by using following syntax

```
exten => s,1,Metmee(100,d)
```

or even

```
exten => s,1,Metmee(,d)
```

For video call use modern ConfBridge application or use specialized software like vmuktu.

Codec have to be setuped in extension properties in sip.conf

Timing of conference call have to be done using dialplan(see gotoif/gotoiftime)

If you are new with asterisk, it is not so nice idea start with such complex staff.
Even if you success in it, resultion application will be not scalable and probalby buggy.

Comment: can you give me an example with ConfBrigde for video call please?

Answer (score 0):

As arheops said, better use ConfBridge:

For use video in ConfBdrige, you can adjust de parameter called video_mode in the bridge profile inside your confbdridge.conf. Also check that you already add the video enable option, and the pertinent codecs in to your sip user:

```
videosupport=yes ;VideoEnable
allow = h263     ;codecs
allow=h263p      ;codecs
```

For more info consult the Asterisk wiki: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge+10